# Can an event based read function ever run out of order?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stdin

Given a situation where I use the nodejs readline library to iterate over each line in the STDIN stream, do some processing on it and write it back out to STDOUT as in the following example:

```
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});
function my_function(line) {
    var output = ...(line);
    process.stdout.write(output);
}
rl.on('line', my_function);
```

I'm concerned that the processing I'm doing will take very different amounts of time depending on the line content so some lines will return very quickly while others takes some time to sort out. Is it possible that `my_function()` will ever run out of order and hence cause the output stream to be scrambled? Should I be looking into using a synchronous loop of some kind instead of this asynchronous event handler?

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript execution itself is single-threaded, so as long as you're only performing synchronous operations inside the event handler, there is no problem.

If you *are* performing *asynchronous* operations inside the event handler, then it is possible that another `'line'` event could be emitted before your asynchronous operation(s) are complete. In that case, you would need to `rl.pause()` first and then `rl.resume()` once you are finished with your asynchronous operations. However, this isn't foolproof since `'line'` events could still be emitted after a `rl.pause()` if the current chunk of data read from the input stream had multiple line breaks.

So if you are performing asynchronous operations inside the event handler, you are probably better off just reading from the stream yourself so that you have more control over the parsing behavior. This is actually pretty easy to do, for example:

```
function parseStream(stream, callback) {
  // Assuming all stream data is text and not binary ...
  var buffer = '';

  var RE_EOL = /\r?\n/g;

  stream.on('data', function(data) {
    buffer += data;
    processBuffer();
  });

  stream.on('end', callback);

  stream.on('error', callback);

  function processBuffer() {
    var idx = RE_EOL.exec(buffer);
    if (~idx) {
      // Found a line ending

      var line = buffer.slice(0, RE_EOL.index);
      buffer = buffer.slice(RE_EOL.index + RE_EOL[0].length);

      stream.pause();
      callback(null, line, processBuffer);
    } else {
      stream.resume();
    }
  }
}

// ...

processStream(process.stdin, function(err, line, done) {
  if (err) throw err;

  if (line === undefined) {
    // No more data will be available (stream ended)
    console.log('(Stream ended!)');
    return;
  }

  // Do something with `line`
  console.log(line);

  // Call `done()` whenever your async operation(s) are all finished
  done();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and advice on how to proceed. Frankly though I'm a little disturbed by how much boilerplate this is turning into just to iterate over a stream one line at a time. I supposed I'm a little too used to life in a Unix shell where linewise operations are the norm. I'm wondering if I wouldn't be better off doing by iteration in something else and  just calling out to this particular script one line at a time. It would be a lot of invocations but considering the overhead of the library I'm actually doing the parsing in it wouldn't be that significant.

Comment: Could you clarify one point? You said ever running `rl.pause()` "isn't foolproof either", but what if I stick strictly to synchronous function calls inside that event handler? If I don't do anything aSync in there am I safe enough to use the code I had?

Comment: If you're only doing sync operations, you don't have to worry about changing anything since the js is single threaded, meaning no other js can be executed while your event handler function is being executed. That means there is no need to pause/resume the readline instance or the input stream. But if you ever do async operations, you will probably need something like the code example I gave instead.